# Jelastic NodeJS support for Let's Encrypt w/o a load balancer

Tags: node.js, lets-encrypt, jelastic

I'm following the [Jelastic Let's Encrypt article](https://jelastic.com/blog/free-ssl-certificates-with-lets-encrypt/), where it is claimed that the list of supported containers would be constantly growing. The [list is actually linked there](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/lets-encrypt/blob/f08448d949878cd196e49c996ab8a9e60154c0d8/manifest.jps#L10) and it does contain the "nodejs" target. This change was added 4 years ago according to `git blame`.
However, when I try to enable the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on my NodeJS application server in Jelastic, I'm getting the following error message:
[image]

So, does Jelastic support Let's Encrypt for NodeJS containers or not? If it does, is there a trick required to get it working?

Of course I could simply add a load balancer to the setup, but adding a load balancer for one single NodeJS application server which sees next to no action is overkill....

Comment: Custom SSL and the Let's Encrypt add-on are separate features.

Comment: Thanks @Damien-Layershift for the feedback. As I said: I'm following the Jelastic Let's Encrypt tutorial. Step 3 says: _"When finished, you can access the environment Settings > Custom SSL section to check that the HTTPS support is active and find the certificate expiration date."_ and depicts the custom SSL panel. So I'm not quite sure I understand your comment?